# How to configure custom trigger filter

Tags: trigger, custom, journeybuilder

I have been doing some test based on the [journey-builder-custom-hello-world](https://github.com/ExactTarget/journey-builder-custom-hello-world) example at Github. I am able to fire it and set data into its Data Extension. I hav tried unsuccessfully so start a Customer Journey using my new Trigger and after some tries I have started to get the same error described at [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58388/cannot-activate-journey-builder-interactions).

I do not have the option to remove all my Interactions, Triggers, Attribute Groups and Data Extensions in my account because I am not the only one is using this environment.

In addition the Custom Trigger [documentation page](https://github.com/ExactTarget/journey-builder-custom-hello-world) is broken:

```
http://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/platform/creating-custom-triggers.html
```

My questions are related with the Filter definition configured in the helloWorldTrigger.js, in the example code:

```
<FilterDefinition Source=\'yoda-tlmk-sample-trigger\'>
  <ConditionSet Operator=\'AND\' ConditionSetName=\'Grouping\'>
    <Condition ID=\'ece15cd0-8893-e311-b943-78e3b50b4f00\' 
                'isParam=\'false\' 
                'Operator=\'Equal\' 
                'conditionValid=\'1\'>
      <Value>
        <![CDATA[' + data.originEventStart + ']]>
      </Value>
    </Condition>
  </ConditionSet>
</FilterDefinition>
```

1. Where can I find the documentation about how to configure these kind of filters?
2. Is the source in the FilterDefinition related with my filter Data Extension?
3. Where is the "Condition ID" coming from? Is it related with any Contact Parameter?
4. Can I retrieve my FilterDefinitions or my Conditions in order to get their IDs?